# How can you make a dialog in HTML and CSS that shrinks automatically while staying centered?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a dialog that auto-shrinks on mobile to take up 80% of the screen space, but maxes out at 750px by 500px on desktop or large tablet. Here's a code snippet of just that (I recommend you click on Full Page):

```css
/* Just some styling to make stuff look nice */
body {
  background: coral;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: #4f00ff;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* Question's focus code */
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: min(750px, 80vw);
  height: min(500px, 80vh);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    Dialog
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to center it. Just trying this doesn't work correctly:

```css
/* Just some styling to make stuff look nice */
body {
  background: coral;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: #4f00ff;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* Question's focus code */
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: min(750px, 80vw);
  height: min(500px, 80vh);
  left: min(calc((100vw - 750px) / 2), 10vw);
  top: min(calc((100vh - 500px) / 2), 10vh);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    Dialog
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any way to do this in plain CSS? Would I have to use media queries instead of the utilities `min`, `max`, `clamp`, and `calc`?

Comment: just use media queries

Comment: Okay. Should I post that as an answer then?

Comment: to unspecific for an anwser. besides of that, it really depends on what you want to do specifically. Another way to implement that would be the use of combination od media queries and `auto-fit/1fr` or `minmax` sizing

Comment: Got it. I'll start trying to figure out how I could use media queries, then.

Comment: For clarification are you trying to center the container, the text or both?

Comment: Just the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can understand from your question you can do it like this. Make sure to add the meta tag in your html.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: coral;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  background: #4f00ff;
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  div {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    Dialog
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks good. Does this mean now my whole page needs to be flexbox?

Comment: With that code yes but you can always use grid in your inner containers. Flex is really great for mobile and desktop support and keeping everything centered. I usually use flex with column direction for the page and change the displays of inner containers if needed to things like grid or maybe flex direction row.

Here's a great resource on flex:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Just finished converting my (WIP) site to use flex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do this. To target the div specifically, I assigned a class "dialog" to the div.

**margin: 0 auto**

```css
/* Just some styling to make stuff look nice */
body {
  background: coral;
  margin: 0;
 
}

.dialog {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: min(750px, 80vw);
  height: min(500px, 80vh);
  background: #4f00ff;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="dialog">
    Dialog
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you can use **flex** by setting the parent to display: flex and use the property justify-content: center.

```css
/* Just some styling to make stuff look nice */
body {
  background: coral;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dialog {
  width: min(750px, 80vw);
  height: min(500px, 80vh);
  background: #4f00ff;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="dialog">
    Dialog
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works great, except that it's not centered vertically. Any way to do that?

Comment: with flex, you can do it by adding another property "align-items: center". I wasn't sure if you wanted it to be aligned vertically so I didn't include that part. In that case you probably also have to set your body (or the target div's parent) height too 100vh, so it get centered to the screen. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Using max-width and similar media queries, this can be possible. Also, the padding was messing with it.

```css
/* Just some styling to make stuff look nice */

body {
  background: coral;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: #4f00ff;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* Question's focus code */

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 10vh;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  div {
    width: 750px;
    left: calc((100vw - 750px) / 2);
  }
}

@media (min-height: 550px) {
  div {
    height: 500px;
    top: calc((100vh - 500px) / 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    Dialog
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```